# What are our options for a Laptop/Notebook and Multi-Monitory support?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors

We have multi-monitor support for our desktops at work/home. 2 or 3 mon's.

We're looking at going to lappy's (preference: Macs but can do 'PC' lappy's) but we need multi-monitor support:

1. No - we don't want to use the laptop monitor as the 2nd monitor. we'll close the lids.
2. No - please no VGA ports. And no, please no debates about why/why not.
3. Yes - a docking station is fine! We don't need multi-monitor support when we are mobile/on-the-road. only at our office desks.

So - what are our options?